# How to properly handle AngularJS $inject annotation with Flowtype

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flowtype

I'm trying to use [Flowtype](https://flowtype.org/) in an AngularJS (1.5) project but it complains about the [$inject annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector). What is the correct way to handle this?

Flow version 0.30.0

**Example code**

navigation/links-controller.js

```
export default class LinksController {

  constructor(navigationService) {
    this.availableLinks = navigationService.availableLinks;
  }
}

LinksController.$inject = ['NavigationService'];
```

navigation/index.js

```
...
import NavigationService from './navigation-service';
import LinksController from './links-controller';

export default angular.module('app.links', [uirouter])
  .config(routing)
  .service('NavigationService', NavigationService)
  .controller('LinksController', LinksController)
  .name;
```

**Example flowtype output**

```
LinksController.$inject = ['NavigationService'];
                ^^^^^^^ property `$inject`. Property not found
```

Comment: I don't really use Flowtype, but your controller doesn't have `$inject` property directly declared, so in fact Flowtype is right - the property is not found. Maybe you can change the config to ignore `$inject` keyword.

Comment: You can only tells **flow** to ignore files matching the specified regular expressions. I don't see any option to ignore specific rules or keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that by creating a class you are defining its interface in Flow.

When you are assigning `$inject` to the class you are effectively adding a new property that was not defined in the class interface and that is a type error in Flow.

You have two options for making this type check in Flow:

**Adding a static property type definition:**

```
class LinksController {
  static $inject: Array<string>;
  constructor() {...}
}

LinksController.$inject = ['NavigationService'];
```

**Adding a static property:**

```
class LinksController {
  static $inject = ['NavigationService'];
  constructor() {...}
}
```

With the second option you are going to need to enable `esproposal.class_static_fields=enable` within the `[options]` section of your `.flowconfig`

Because this is a proposal not yet added to the JavaScript standard and not available in any browsers, you will also need to compile it with something like [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) (you'll need either the [stage-2 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) or the [transform-class-properties plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)).

Comment: Thank you. I was already experimenting with the second approach but class fields and static properties are at stage 2 so I'm not sure if I want to use them. I'll define a superclass with static property type definition and flow should stop complaining about $inject.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using external dependency injection then you might want to link the functions like below.

```
angular
   .module('app',[])
   .controller('LinkCtrl', LinkCtrl);

LinkCtrl.$inject = ['NavigationService'];
```

Can you please share your full snipper if you have exactly done like above?

Comment: I've updated my question with some examples. AngularJS app is working per se and it's not a problem with how services and controllers are registered or injected. It's just that the flow is complaining about missing property.

Comment: can you share the interface file you have created for angular js?